# PHP - Echoing a variable in color

Tags: php

Im new to learning PHP as you might have guessed. I have the contents of a .txt file echoed but I would like it to stand out more, so I figured I would make it a different colour.

My code without colour:

```
<?php
$file = fopen("instructions.txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file");
while(!feof($file))
{
echo  fgets($file);
}
fclose($file);
?>
```

I have researched this and seen suggestions to others to use a div style, however this didn't work for me, it gave me red errors all the way down the page instead! I think its because I'm using 'fgets' not just a variable? Is there a way to colour the echo red?

The code I tried but doesn't work:

```
echo "<div style=\"color: red;\">fgets($file)</div>";
```

Comment: `echo "<div style=\"color: red;\">" . fgets($file) . "</div>";`

Comment: Hint: use `.` to concatentate two strings. Hint#2: code inside string literals won't execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(In general) You need to separate the actual PHP code from the literal portions of your strings. One way is to use the string concatenation operator `.`. E.g.

`echo "<div style=\"color: red;\">" . fgets($file) . "</div>";`

[String Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: fyi, it's better to use single/double quotes so you don't have to escape quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Other answer already told that you can't use a function call in a double quoted string. Let additionally mention that for formatting only tasks a `<span>` element is better suited than a `<div>` element.

Like this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span

Answer (score 0):

**You should try:**

```
<div style="color: red;"><?= fgets($file);?></div>
```

**Note:** `<?=` is an short hand method for `<?php echo fgets($file);?>`

Answer (score 0):

This version does not need to escape double quotes:

```
echo '<div style="color:red;">' . fgets($file) . '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the concatenate operator `.` as has already been mentioned but IMO it's cleaner to use `sprintf` like this:

```
echo sprintf("<div style='color: red;'>%s</div>", fgets($file));
```

This method comes into it's own if you have two sets of text that you want to insert a string in different places eg:

```
echo sprintf("<div style='color: red;'>%s</div><div style='color: blue;'>%s</div>", fgets($file), fgets($file2));
```